# monodevelop compling error; why does misses assembly reference if those exists?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I made a GTK# 2.0 Project from MonoDevelop, and it generated two files:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace Application
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
            win.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

I Pressed 'Debug' Button, Not modefying any code.
Then Compiler printed this:

```
The type or namespace name `Init' does not exist in the namespace `Application'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234)
The type or namespace name `Run' does not exist in the namespace `Application'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234)
The type or namespace name `Quit' does not exist in the namespace `Application'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234)
```

I saw Reference list on Solution Tab, and there exists Gtk.Application.Init,Run,Quit. Then why does this error occurs?

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of MonoDevelop? Do you have all the needed packages installed?
I'm using MonoDevelop 7.3.3 with Mono 5.10 on Manjaro. What is your setup?
You need to install Gtk#, anyway.

Comment: MonoDevelop 6.2.1 at DragonFlyBSD; anyway, I've solved. I edited Application.Init,Run,Quit to Gtk.Application.Init,Run,Quit - That was the cure.

Comment: If your question was accurate, then there is no explanation of why putting "Gtk." prefixing that calls solved your problem (you had a "using Gtk;" in the top of the class).
Nevermind, I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: @JihooByeon if you solved it, please answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

modify Program.cs to:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace Application
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gtk.Application.Init();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
            win.Show();
            Gtk.Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

modify MainWindow.cs to:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Gtk.Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```